# PL/SQL Procedure - List of Records as Input

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, stored-functions

I have a table Students with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS
(
    SID    VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)    NOT NULL,
    SNAME  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)    NOT NULL, . . .
)
```

I want to create a stored procedure that will take a list of students as input argument each item in the list will have sid and sname.

What will be the type of the input parameter and how to define it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass in an Oracle collection type as a parameter.

The collection could be a key value pair such as an associative array indexed by a varchar.
In that example, the index could be the SID and the value could be the SNAME.

Read here to learn about collections: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm

And here for associative arrays in particular: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/AssociativeArrays9i.php

Alternatively you could pass two parameters, both collections holding varchar values (such as DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2_TABLE types) the first holding the SID and the second holding the corresponding SNAME values they would effectively be linked by their index number.
See here for DBMS_SQL defined types: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm

Hope it helps...

EDIT:

If you are declaring all types and performing all actions within a package then:

```
-- Declare type
TYPE student_coltype IS TABLE OF student%ROWTYPE
     INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
-- Declare variable of type
student_col student_coltype;
```

If you want global types then you'll have to explicitly declare the columns:

```
CREATE TYPE student_rec
AS OBJECT 
(SID   VARCHAR2(10),
 SNAME VARCHAR2(50));

CREATE TYPE student_collection
AS TABLE OF student_rec;
```

You can then use the student collection type with your DB to pass collections of student data into and out of procedures and functions.

The docs for using oracle objects are here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjint.htm

Comment: But the table may expand horizontally in future, I need something that is logically equivalent to List<Students> in Java.

Comment: If you mean there could be more columns in the table, then you could still use an Oracle collection. The collection would be a collection of records. Define your record based upon the STUDENTS table %ROWTYPE and it will dynamically change as your table does.

Comment: Is this correct? TYPE studentList IS VARRAY(100) OF students%ROWTYPE;

Comment: That would create a VARRAY, personally i'd use a different type (i'll edit my answer with some syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type for your couple SID, SNAME:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE O_STUDENT AS OBJECT (
  SID                           VARCHAR2(20)
, SNAME                         VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

Then create a collection type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE T_STUDENT AS TABLE OF O_STUDENT;
```

Then use T_STUDENT as the type of parameter of your procedure. You can insert values in a variable of type T_STUDENT with SQL INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
   create or replace procedure show_students is
    begin
      dbms_output.put_line('------------------------');     
      dbms_output.put_line('Student ID| Student Name|');
      dbms_output.put_line('------------------------');
      for i in( select * from students )
      loop
        dbms_output.put(i.sid||' |');
        dbms_output.put(i.sname||'        |');
      end loop;
      dbms_output.put_line('------------------------------');
    end;
    /
    show errors;
   set serveroutput on;
   execute show_students;
```